# compile errors in singleton inside head file

Tags: c++, singleton

this is my class:

```
#ifndef POINTPOOL_H_
#define POINTPOOL_H_

#include <list>
#include <iostream>

#include "ofPoint.h"

// adapted from https://gist.github.com/1124832

class PointPool
{
    private:
        std::list<ofPoint*> resources;
        static PointPool* instance;

        PointPool() {};

    public:
        ~PointPool() {};                      // 1
        static pointPool* getInstance()       // 2
        {
            if (instance == 0)
            {
                instance = new PointPool();
            }
            return instance;
        }

        Resource* getPoint()
        {
            if (resources.empty())
            {
                std::cout << "Creating new." << std::endl;
                return new ofPoint();
            }
            else
            {
                std::cout << "Reusing existing." << std::endl;
                ofPoint* resource = resources.front();
                resources.pop_front();
                return resource;
            }
        }

        void disposePoint(ofPoint* object)
        {
            object->x = 0;
            object->y = 0;
            object->z = 0;
            resources.push_back(object);
        }
};

PointPool* PointPool::instance = 0;

#endif /* POINTPOOL_H_ */
```

i get

```
expected unqualified-id at end of input
```

at comment 1 and

```
expected ‘;’ before ‘*’ token
```

at comment 2 i tried to google but i don't fine a link between this compiler message error and my code..

Comment: Singleton??????? Why???????????????????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change this:

```
static pointPool* getInstance()
```

To this:

```
static PointPool* getInstance()
```

The semicolons after your constructor and destructor are also unnecessary. And, as Ed mentioned, the definition of PointPool::instance must not be in the header.

Comment: capitals always get you sometimes - guess it is capital punishment!

Answer (score 1):

This line `PointPool* PointPool::instance = 0;` should be in the .cpp file - otherwise you are going to have multiple copies.

Answer (score 1):

You also have a typo in `pointPool*`, which should be `PointPool*`. Fixing it should clear both errors.